# Can't break out of innermost while loop -- Bash - Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path, ffmpeg

Whenever the two MD5 check sums ($SUMCHK1 & $SUMCHK2) match up in this script I get stuck in the innermost while loop, so the script never ends. When the two log files match, I get an endless echo of the two md5sums on the screen.

```
#!/bin/bash

FULLPATH=$1
FPS=$2
AVI=$(basename $1)
AVIDIR=$HOME/q7video/$AVI
TMPFILE=$AVIDIR/tmp.txt
TMPFILE2=$AVIDIR/tmp2.txt
NEWFILES=$AVIDIR/tmp3.txt
FFLOG=$AVIDIR/ffmpeg.log
LOGFILE=$AVIDIR/log.log
FACESDIR=$AVIDIR/faces

# CREATE FOLDER STRUCTURE, NO ERROR IF DIR PRE-EXISTS
mkdir --parents $AVIDIR
mkdir --parents $FACESDIR
touch $TMPFILE $TMPFILE2 $NEWFILES $LOGFILE
echo $AVI > $LOGFILE

# DUMP THUMBNAILS FROM SPECIFIED AVI FILE
ffmpeg -i $FULLPATH -f image2 -vf fps=fps=$FPS $AVIDIR/$AVI%03d.jpg </dev/null >/dev/null 2>$FFLOG &

# DELAY TO ALLOW LOOP A WORKING DIRECTORY BEFORE START
sleep 2

#TOUCH FILES TO PREVENT NO FILE ERROR
touch $TMPFILE $TMPFILE2

# INITIALIZE VARIABLE FOR LOOP
CHECK=`pgrep ffmpeg`
I=0
SUMCHK1=`md5sum $TMPFILE`
SUMCHK2=`md5sum $TMPFILE2`

while [[ "$CHECK" -gt "$I" ]]; do
    sleep 2
    echo FFMPEG RUNNING
    ls $AVIDIR/*.jpg > $TMPFILE
    while [[ "$SUMCHK1" != "$SUMCHK2" ]]; do
        comm -23 $TMPFILE $TMPFILE2 > $NEWFILES
        while read F ; do
            echo $F
            echo $F >> $TMPFILE2
            echo $F >> $LOGFILE
            python opencvtest.py $F >> $LOGFILE
        done < $NEWFILES
        ls $AVIDIR/*.jpg > $TMPFILE
        SUMCHK1=`md5sum $TMPFILE`
        SUMCHK2=`md5sum $TMPFILE2`
        echo $SUMCHK1
        echo $SUMCHK2
    done
    CHECK=`pgrep ffmpeg`
    echo $CHECK
done



# COPY IMAGES WITH A FACE TO FACESDIR


# CLEANUP LOGS
#rm $TMPFILE $TMPFILE2 $NEWFILES
```

Comment: The two variables will never have the same value, because each includes the name of the file whose checksum it holds.

Comment: Why are you comparing the process ID of an instance of FFMPEG to 0?

Comment: yes I have the same behavior on my side, md5sum outputs the hash plus filename, e.g.  `54328f6b27a45c51986ed436f3f609bf  .profile`. You should remove the last part with `| cut -d' ' -f1`

Comment: For the process id check, I was looking for something quick and easy to make sure ffmpeg was finished, and the only bash conditional I could get working was comparing the output of pgrep against 0, since in theory it should never be a zero. I don't know what the conditional in bash would be to catch a null return. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without the need of checksums.

```
# INITIALIZE VARIABLE FOR LOOP
CHECK=`pgrep ffmpeg`
I=0

while [[ "$CHECK" -gt "$I" ]]; do
    sleep 2
    echo FFMPEG RUNNING

    # get the current file list
    ls -1 $AVIDIR/*.jpg | sort > $TMPFILE

    # compare current file list with previous list and extract new file list
    comm -23 $TMPFILE $TMPFILE2 > $NEWFILES

    # process new files
    while read F ; do
        echo $F
        echo $F >> $LOGFILE
        python opencvtest.py $F >> $LOGFILE
    done < $NEWFILES

    # save the current file list to be used as previous list in next run
    cp $TMPFILE $TMPFILE2

    CHECK=`pgrep ffmpeg`
    echo $CHECK
done
```

As an aside, loop body should be executed once more after `ffmpeg` has completed to make sure the last set of images are not skipped from processing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I'm still getting endless execution on the innermost loop with this change as well.

Comment: What did you mean by another loop body should be executed? Is their an easy elegant way to do this without repeating the whole thing again in the script?

Comment: @KennyPowers When you say inner most loop, is it the `while read F ; do` or is it the other one that check ffmpeg process status? If its the `while read F ...` one, what happens when you comment out the python script? When that's commented, does it output new file names as new images are created?